# Compress/Deflate @font-face fonts

Tags: css, apache, fonts, font-face, compression

I am using the @font-face CSS property to load a special font for headings on a website, and I want Apache to send the font compressed to reduce loading time.

However, the "AddOutputFilterByType" declaration in Apache 2's deflate module only accepts mime types and, as AFAIK, neither opentype nor truetype have registered mime types.

So, how do I configure Apache to deflate/compress font.otf or font.ttf files?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Came up with a solution:

Use Apache's `AddType` declaration to add a custom mime type and then use that mime type in the `AddOutputFilterByType` declaration.

For example, for opentype and truetype fonts:

```
Addtype font/opentype .otf
Addtype font/truetype .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css font/opentype font/truetype
```

Both these declarations require their appropriate modules to be active: `mod_mime` and `mod_deflate`. And for best practice, the `AddType` declaration should be in the mime.conf file, and the `AddOutputFilterByType` declaration should be in the deflate.conf file. See your particular distribution's help files for enabling and configuring Apache modules.

Comment: Very late, but anyone else looking for this may also be interested in the HTML5Boilerplate approach, which is similar but more comprehensive; see http://html5boilerplate.com/template/htaccess.txt?.xml.

Comment: The link for h5bp's .htaccess has [changed](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess).

Comment: This is the correct URL for the HTML5 Boilerplate:
https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache

The repository is plenty of amazing htaccess snippets, for example to leverage the browser cache (https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/web_performance/expires_headers.conf).